# Allow outside touch for DialogFragment (Listview onitemclick not working)

Tags: android, window, touch, dialogfragment

When i am showing dialog fragment i want outside elements to be clickable

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    getView().post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Window dialogWindow = getDialog().getWindow();

            // Make the dialog possible to be outside touch
            dialogWindow.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
            dialogWindow.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

            getView().invalidate();
        }
    });
}
```

i am using this in my code but onitemclick of listview and gridview are not working where as button clicks working any suggestions please ?

Comment: its working for me.
just used  setStyle(STYLE_NO_INPUT , 0); in oncreate method of dialogfragment  :)

Comment: outside elements i am able to click but the views in dialog fragment are not responding :(

Answer (score 1):

Set `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` flag instead of `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` flag as the following

```
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to create a full Activity for a lot of my dialogs.  It's very simple to give the Activity a theme that makes it look like a dialog.  In my manifest, I list my activity like so:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".UserLogin"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        android:theme="@style/ActivityDialog"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
  </activity>
```

and in my styles.xml, I define the theme as:

```
  <style name="ActivityDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
  </style>
```

The last item in the style does it all for you. Turn it on or off to manage clicking outside your "dialog"